# How can I copy data from one column to another in the same table?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to copy data from column A to column B for all records in a table in SQL?

Answer (score 754, accepted):

How about this

```
UPDATE table SET columnB = columnA;
```

This will update every row.

Comment: This will also work if you want to transfer old value to other column and update the first one: `UPDATE table SET columnA = 'new value', columnB = columnA`. Like other answer says - don't forget the WHERE clause to update only what's needed.

Comment: I thinking in some complex proc doing a loop at each record when the answer is so simple

Comment: This shows the power of a declarative language! Most of us are so familiar with imperative programming languages that we forget simplicity.

Answer (score 164):

```
UPDATE table_name SET
    destination_column_name=orig_column_name
WHERE condition_if_necessary
```

Comment: @Mark, this actually makes sense, why is this downvoted? I had a situation where I need to copy a date value from one column to other columns, and it only applies to SOME of the columns, and not all. So having a WHERE in the statement would be necessary.

Comment: @finnTheHuman The question asks how to " copy data from all records" which the earlier answer answers correctly so this does not add anything

Comment: @Mark "How does this differ from the old accepted answer", it has a WHERE clause.

"so this does not add anything", I disagree, it adds something. it's a good point to include WHERE clause IF NECESSARY.

we should be responsible on downvoting answers.

haters gon' hate

Comment: In my case I added a last_seen column. `UPDATE user SET last_seen = first_seen WHERE last_seen IS NULL`

Comment: ...but I need a clause in mine that limits it to 100 records /s

Answer (score 5):

This will update all the rows in that columns if safe mode is not enabled.

`UPDATE table SET columnB = columnA;`

If safe mode is enabled then you will need to use a where clause.
I use primary key as greater than 0 basically all will be updated

`UPDATE table SET columnB = columnA where table.column>0;`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy a column to another column with a different data type in PostgresSQL, you must cast/convert to the data type first, otherwise it will return

> Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  column "test_date" is of type timestamp without
> time zone but expression is of type character varying LINE 1: update
> table_name set test_date = date_string_col
> ^ HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

An example of converting varchar to timestamp:

```
update table_name set timestamp_col = date_string_col::TIMESTAMP;
```

An example of converting varchar to int:

```
update table_name set int_column = string_col::INTEGER;
```

but any column type(except file or the similar) can be copied to string(`character varying`) without cast the type.