# How do I duplicate a column in a SQL Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have a `table` named `Table1`. Assuming I want to duplicate a column named `SubCategory` into a new column called `SubCategory2` (with the same values as in column `SubCategory`), what would be the `SQL` `syntax` to do this?

Note: Idea here is to keep column `Subcategory` but create another column `SubCategory2` and modify some specific values in that new column.

Example (assuming Table1 has only 2 columns):

```
Serial  Subcategory
  1        UK
  2        UK
  3        FR
  4        DE
```

Expected output:

```
Serial  Subcategory  Subcategory2
  1        UK           UK
  2        UK           UK
  3        FR           FR
  4        DE           DE
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A combination of [Add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92082/add-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server) and [How can I copy data from one column to another in the same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308594/how-can-i-copy-data-from-one-column-to-another-in-the-same-table) woold look something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD SubCategory2 {Type of subcategory 1} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
UPDATE Table1 SET SubCategory2 = SubCategory;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Table1


---------Query-----------

select * , SubCategory as SubCategory2 FROM Table1

----------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` instead when selecting records

```
     SELECT Serial ,Subcategory,  case 
      when Subcategory='somevalue' 
      then Subcategory else null end
     'Subcategory2'  from table
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 use ['database name']
   go
 insert into table1 ('subcategory2') select subgategory from table1;
```

Comment: This will add new rows, and not update existing rows.

Comment: Can you check example and expected out of the question. I think I have answered it as per the example is given.