# Duplicate Cell String

Tags: sql, database

I have a database table for Contacts structured.

```
ID = 1    
Full_Name = Joe Bloggs    
Primary Email = SomeEmail@Test.com    
Secondary Email = Null
```

is it possible to use an SQL query to duplicate the primary email into the secondary email for each contact like so:

```
ID = 1    
Full_Name = Joe Bloggs    
Primary_Email = SomeEmail@Test.com    
Secondary_Email = SomeEmail@Test.com    

ID = 2    
Full_Name = Ruth Jones    
Primary_Email = TestEMail@Test.com    
Secondary_Email = TestEMail@Test.com
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: dupe of [How can I copy data from one column to another in the same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308594/how-can-i-copy-data-from-one-column-to-another-in-the-same-table) and should be answered by any half-decent intro to SQL. I don't see why you would duplicate in this case, though; I'd expect `Secondary_Email` to be `null` if there was only a primary address. That said, perhaps this would be best expressed as a related table of email addresses and types/priorities/etc per person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set it:

```
UPDATE your_table SET Secondary_Email = Primary_Email
```

Comment: Presumably you might want to add `where Secondary_Email is null`. It's not clear from the question though.