# Add new column in database by migration c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a table which contains two columns (A and B).column A has default value of 1 or 0. I want to add new column C, its default value is 0 and C'values depends on A'value.
How can I do that using migration in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Read the part about computed columns [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations).

Comment: "add new column C, its default value is 0 and C'values depends on A'value."Do you mean copy data from one column to another in the same table? If so, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308594/how-can-i-copy-data-from-one-column-to-another-in-the-same-table)

Answer (score 1):

At first define your columns in a class for example named "Sample", than define a dbSet property in your application context , something like this

```
public DbSet<Sample> Contacts { get; set; }
```

If you want to set default value for your columns you can override OnModelCreating method in your application context and set a default value for your columns , like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Sample>()
        .Propery(p => p.A)
        .HasDefaultValue(0);
}
```

In above code "A" is your intended column name .
Than write `Add-Migration` in command console to create new migration , than write `Update-Database` .

Hope it will be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
        name: "C",
        table: "MyTableName",
        nullable: false);

    migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE MyTableName SET C=CASE  
                    WHEN A = 0 THEN 0 
                    WHEN B = 1 THEN 1 
                    ...
                    ELSE 0
                END  WHERE ...);
}
```

use whatever condition you need in migrationBuilder